# Python PIL How to pass an image as a parameter and use it for processing in another function

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I do not want to save images from camera to disk so I am trying to pass the PIL image as a parameter like the code below

array = np.array(array)
  im = Image.fromstring("RGB", (imageWidth, imageHeight), array)
  return im

I want to access this from another function and do some image processing as below:

```
lower_blue = np.array([50, 0, 0])
upper_blue = np.array([255, 50, 50])

lower = np.array(lower_blue, dtype = "uint8")
upper = np.array(upper_blue, dtype = "uint8")

mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)  
cv2.imwrite("mask.png",mask)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)    
cv2.imwrite("output.png",output)
thresh = 90   

gray = cv2.cvtColor(output,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,thresh,thresh*2)  
cv2.imwrite("edges.png",edges)
```

I getan error "src is not a numpy array or a scalar"
How can I pass this as a parameter? If not, how can I pass the image into memory and then read from it.

I tried converting using np.array but all I get is a red image. The original image is not interpreted well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work using the code below but is this the correct way to do it?
image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(im, dtype='uint8'), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)